# How to pretty print XML from the command line?

Tags: xml, unix, command-line

Related: [How can I pretty-print JSON in (unix) shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352098/how-to-pretty-print-json-from-the-command-line)

Is there a (unix) shell script to format XML in human-readable form?

Basically, I want it to transform the following:

```
<root><foo a="b">lorem</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>
```

... into something like this:

```
<root>
    <foo a="b">lorem</foo>
    <bar value="ipsum" />
</root>
```

Comment: To have `xmllint` available on Debian systems, you need to install the package `libxml2-utils` (`libxml2` does not provide this tool, at least not on Debian 5.0 "Lenny" and 6.0 "Squeeze").

Comment: web browsers (e.g. firefox / chrome) tend to do a good job of pretty-printing XML documents these days.  (posting as a comment because this isn't a CLI, but a very convenient alternative)

Answer (score 1165, accepted):

##### xmllint from [libxml2](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2)

```sh
xmllint --format file.xml
```

(On Debian based distributions install the [libxml2-utils](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libxml2-utils) package)

##### xml_pp from the [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) module

```sh
xml_pp < file.xml
```

(On Debian based distributions install the [xml-twig-tools](https://packages.debian.org/sid/xml-twig-tools) package)

#### [XMLStarlet](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlstar/)

```sh
xmlstarlet format --indent-tab file.xml
```

##### [Tidy](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5)

```sh
tidy -xml -i -q file.xml
```

##### Python's [xml.dom.minidom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)

```sh
echo '<root><foo a="b">lorem</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>' |
  python -c 'import sys, xml.dom.minidom; print(xml.dom.minidom.parseString(sys.stdin.read()).toprettyxml())'
```

##### [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) (my own project)

```sh
saxon-lint --indent --xpath '/' file.xml
```

##### [saxon-HE](https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon)

```sh
echo '<root><foo a="b">lorem</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>' |
  java -cp /usr/share/java/saxon/saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query \
       -s:- -qs:/ '!indent=yes'
```

##### [xidel](https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html)

```sh
xidel --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent -se . -s file.xml
```

(Credit to **[Reino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65051701/465183)**)

#### Output for all commands:

```xml
<root>
  <foo a="b">lorem</foo>
  <bar value="ipsum"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Good, quick answer. The first option seems like it'll be more ubiquitous on modern *nix installs. A minor point; but can it be called without working through an intermediate file? I.e., `echo '<xml .. />' | xmllint --some-read-from-stdn-option`?

Comment: The package is `libxml2-utils` in my beautiful ubuntu.

Comment: Do you know how to wrap long lines?

Comment: for the `xml_pp` option: you can install from the repositories `xml-twig-tools` (ubuntu)

Comment: Note that the "cat data.xml | xmllint --format - | tee data.xml" does not work. On my system it sometimes worked for small files, but always truncated huge files. If you really want to do anything in place read http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files/

Comment: I did this to use **xmllint**:
`find . -name "*.xml" -exec xmllint --format --output {} {} \;`
You have to can specify a file to it put the result of the pretty print. In my case, I just wanted to update the file, so the ouput file was the sameone as the input.

Comment: To solve `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 805: ordinal not in range(128)` in python version you want to define `PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8"`: `cat some.xml | PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8" python -c 'import sys;import xml.dom.minidom;s=sys.stdin.read();print xml.dom.minidom.parseString(s).toprettyxml()' > pretty.xml`

Comment: `xmllint` seems to silently refuse to do any formatting if lines are too long.

Comment: It seems tidy is only option to put attributes on separate lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20#comment19202573_9942822 shows another fix for the unicode error in python when piping to a file.

Comment: Note that **tidy** can also **format xml with no root element**. This is useful to format through a pipe, xml sections (e.g. extracted from logs). `echo '<x></x><y></y>' | tidy -xml -iq`

Comment: Does any of these options work with `tail`? I'm able to `tail` a streaming log from a remote application which has XML fragments in it and would like the XML fragments to get formatted as the output stream rather than the formatting program hanging until `tail` is killed. I tried `tidy` and it only spits out format warnings as they are encountered.

Comment: didn't find any coloring options? any hints? for now I use vim to get coloring, but then I have to create a newly formatted xml to have good readability again

Comment: Which of these options are portable enough to run on Windows?

Answer (score 190):

`xmllint --format yourxmlfile.xml`

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) is a command line XML tool and is included in `libxml2` (http://xmlsoft.org/).

================================================

*Note: If you don't have `libxml2` installed you can install it by doing the following:*

**CentOS**

```
cd /tmp
wget ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
tar xzf libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz
cd libxml2-2.8.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd
```

**Ubuntu**

`sudo apt-get install libxml2-utils`

**Cygwin**

`apt-cyg install libxml2`

**MacOS**

To install this on MacOS with Homebrew just do:
`brew install libxml2`

**Git**

Also available on Git if you want the code:
`git clone git://git.gnome.org/libxml2`

Comment: sputnick's answer contains this information, but crmpicco's answer is the most useful answer here to the general question about how to pretty print XML.

Comment: we can write out that formatted xml output to some other xml file and use that.. eg xmllint --format yourxmlfile.xml >> new-file.xml

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 you can use the following: `sudo apt-get install libxml2-utils`

Comment: This works on Windows too; [`git`](https://git-scm.com) for Windows [download](https://git-scm.com/download/win) even installs a recent version of `xmllint`. 
Example: `"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\xmllint.exe" --format QCScaper.test@borland.com.cds.xml > QCScaper.test@borland.com.pretty-printed.cds.xml`

Comment: From MacOS with libxml2 installed via brew. To unminify an xml and save it to a new file for me it worked this command `xmllint --format in.xml > out.xml`

Answer (score 46):

You can also use [tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/), which may need to be installed first (e.g. on Ubuntu: sudo `apt-get install tidy`).

For this, you would issue something like following:

```
tidy -xml -i your-file.xml > output.xml
```

Note: has many additional readability flags, but word-wrap behavior is a bit annoying to untangle (http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html).

Comment: Helpful, because I couldn't get xmllint to add linebreaks to a single line xml file. Thanks!

Comment: `tidy` works well for me too. Unlike `hxnormalize`, this done actually closes the `<body>` tag.

Comment: BTW, here are some options that I have found useful: `tidy --indent yes --indent-spaces 4 --indent-attributes yes --wrap-attributes yes --input-xml yes --output-xml yes < InFile.xml > OutFile.xml`.

Comment: Great tip @VictorYarema. I combined it with pygmentize and added it to my .bashrc:  

`alias prettyxml='tidy --indent yes --indent-spaces 4 --indent-attributes yes --wrap-attributes yes --input-xml yes --output-xml yes | pygmentize -l xml'`

 and then can `curl url | prettyxml`

Answer (score 21):

#### Without installing anything on macOS / most Unix.

Use `tidy`

`cat filename.xml | tidy -xml -iq`

Redirecting viewing a file with cat to tidy specifying the file type of xml and to indent while quiet output will suppress error output. JSON also works  with `-json`.

Comment: You don't need the `cat` step: `tidy -xml -iq filename.xml`. Also, you can even do `tidy -xml -iq filename.xml` using the `-m` option to *modify* the original file...

Answer (score 15):

You didn't mention a file, so I assume you want to provide the XML string as standard input on the command line.  In that case, do the following:

```
$ echo '<root><foo a="b">lorem</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>' | xmllint --format -
```

Answer (score 14):

[xmllint support formatting in-place](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2010-August/msg00005.html):

```bash
for f in *.xml; do xmllint -o $f --format $f; done
```

As Daniel Veillard has written:

> I think
> `xmllint -o tst.xml --format tst.xml`
> should be safe as the parser will fully load the input into a tree
> before opening the output to serialize it.

Indent level is controlled by `XMLLINT_INDENT` environment variable which is by default 2 spaces. Example how to change indent to 4 spaces:

```bash
XMLLINT_INDENT='    '  xmllint -o out.xml --format in.xml
```

You may have lack with `--recover` option when you XML documents are broken. Or try weak HTML parser with strict XML output:

```bash
xmllint --html --xmlout <in.xml >out.xml
```

`--nsclean`, `--nonet`, `--nocdata`, `--noblanks` etc may be useful. Read man page.

```bash
apt-get install libxml2-utils
dnf install libxml2
apt-cyg install libxml2
brew install libxml2
```

Answer (score 4):

This simple(st) solution doesn't provide indentation, but it is nevertheless much easier on the human eye. Also it allows the xml to be handled more easily by simple tools like grep, head, awk, etc.

Use `sed` to replace '<' with itself preceeded with a newline.

And as [mentioned by Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16090892/1501497), it's probably not a good idea to use this in production.

```bash
# check you are getting more than one line out
sed 's/</\n</g' sample.xml | wc -l

# check the output looks generally ok
sed 's/</\n</g' sample.xml | head

# capture the pretty xml in a different file
sed 's/</\n</g' sample.xml > prettySample.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for this reply that uses nothing needed to download.

Comment: `sed` is not a xml parser

Answer (score 3):

This took me forever to find something that works on my mac. Here's what worked for me:

```
brew install xmlformat
cat unformatted.html | xmlformat
```

Answer (score 1):

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
$ xidel -s input.xml -e . --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
$ xidel -s input.xml -e 'serialize(.,{"indent":true()})'

$ echo '<root><foo a="b">lorem</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>' | \
  xidel -se . --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
$ echo '<root><foo a="b">lorem</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>' | \
  xidel -se 'serialize(.,{"indent":true()})'
```

Comment: The first solution appears to be out of date as neither option is in `xidel --help` and although the second solution throws no error (the echoed solution needs `-` after `xidel` to receive standard input) this also does not indent the xml.

Comment: @potong Please use an [up-to-date binary](https://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html#downloads).

Comment: This was based on the last official release Xidel 0.9.8.

Answer (score 1):

[yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) can be used to pretty print XML.
It has an option to define the indent.

```bash
yq --input-format xml --output-format xml --indent 2
```

Comment: there is also yq -P but I tried it and looks like not really working. Just `yq --input-format xml --output-format xml` produced a well formatted XML

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

**Disclaimer:** you should usually prefer installing a mature tool like `xmllint` to do a job like this. XML/HTML can be a horribly mutilated mess. However, there are valid situations where using existing tooling is preferable over manually installing new ones, and where it is also a safe bet the XML's source is valid (enough). I've written this script for one of those cases, but they are rare, so precede with caution.

---

I'd like to add a pure Bash solution, as it is not 'that' difficult to just do it by hand, and sometimes you won't want to install an extra tool to do the job.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

declare -i currentIndent=0
declare -i nextIncrement=0
while read -r line ; do
  currentIndent+=$nextIncrement
  nextIncrement=0
  if [[ "$line" == "</"* ]]; then # line contains a closer, just decrease the indent
    currentIndent+=-1
  else
    dirtyStartTag="${line%%>*}"
    dirtyTagName="${dirtyStartTag%% *}"
    tagName="${dirtyTagName//</}"
    # increase indent unless line contains closing tag or closes itself
    if [[ ! "$line" =~ "</$tagName>" && ! "$line" == *"/>"  ]]; then
      nextIncrement+=1
    fi
  fi

  # print with indent
  printf "%*s%s" $(( $currentIndent * 2 )) # print spaces for the indent count
  echo $line
done <<< "$(cat - | sed 's/></>\n</g')" # separate >< with a newline
```

Paste it in a script file, and pipe in the xml.
This assumes the xml is all on one line, and there are no extra spaces anywhere. One could easily add some extra `\s*` to the regexes to fix that.

Comment: Hope to never see this somewhere as a sysadmin -_-

Comment: @GillesQuenot What do you mean? Is there a security risk I'm not seeing?

Comment: Because parsing XML/HTML with anything else than a real parser is (or will be soon) plain buggy. If it's a small personal script on a personal computer, up to you, but for production, no way. It will break !

Comment: I agree XML/HTML can be horribly mutilated, but it does depend on the source. I wrote this for some XML we generate ourselves, so it is a pretty safe bet there.

Comment: Until an intern change the way XML is made :)

Answer (score 0):

I would:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ cat ugly.xml 


<root><foo a="b">lorem</foo><bar value="ipsum" /></root>

nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ basex
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> 
> create database pretty
Database 'pretty' created in 231.32 ms.
> 
> open pretty
Database 'pretty' was opened in 0.05 ms.
> 
> set parser xml
PARSER: xml
> 
> add ugly.xml
Resource(s) added in 161.88 ms.
> 
> xquery .
<root>
  <foo a="b">lorem</foo>
  <bar value="ipsum"/>
</root>
Query executed in 179.04 ms.
> 
> exit
Have fun.
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$
```

if only because then it's "in" a database, and not "just" a file.  Easier to work with, to my mind.

Subscribing to the belief that others have worked this problem out already.  If you prefer, no doubt `eXist` might even be "better" at formatting `xml`, or as good.

You can always query the data various different ways, of course.  I kept it as simple as possible.  You can just use a GUI, too, but you specified console.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my cli tool xmq (https://libxmq.org) to pretty print and syntax highlight XML and HTML. Note that it renders the XML/HTML/JSON in the XMQ format which is easier to read and edit. There is however a 1-1 mapping between XMQ and XML. The tool is very useful for analyzing large xml and html files.

The xmq tool also includes a pager for the terminal: `xmq file.xml page`

The tool can also render into a temporary html file which is automatically viewed in your default browser: `xmq file.xml browse`

It picks the color scheme from your terminals background color (light or dark), but you can override it:

`XMQ_BG=dark xmq file.xml browse`

`XMQ_BG=light xmq file.xml browse`

It works in a pipeline as well: `curl https://slashdot.org | xmq delete //script delete //style page`

Apart from deleting xpath matched nodes, there are other commands to convert to and from xmq/xml/html/json and apply transformations to the content.