# Output alignment structure-preserving

Tags: bash, shell

Here's my output:

```
   <activity>
       <intent-filter>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

How can I left align the output with the same structure? (activity tag block left align)

Note: There are different spaces and tabs at the beginning.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You just want to get rid of the whitespace at the beginning of all the lines?

Comment: Can you show what your desired output is? Also, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090869/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-the-command-line

Comment: You earlier posted an answer which said that you were using the `sed` line that I had suggested. Don't forget to upvote the answers that you find useful (using the ^) and accept your favourite answer (click the ✔). When you accept an answer, this marks your problem as solved and gives both parties a small reward.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output through:

```
sed -r 's/^\s*//'
```

`^` matches the beginning of the line. `\s` matches whitespace characters, and `*` means to match any number of them in a row.

Answer (score 0):

To remove three spaces from the start of each line, you can use:

```
sed 's/^ \{3\}//' file   # or
sed -r 's/^ {3}//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want:

```
file="somefile.xml"
spaces=$(sed -n "/<activity>/s/^\( *\)<.*/\1/p" $file)
sed "/<activity>/,/<\/activity>/s/^ */$spaces/" $file
```

this for the next file

```
<other>
   <some>
   </some>
   <activity>
       <intent-filter>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <other2>
      <some>
   </other2>
</other>
```

produces

```
<other>
   <some>
   </some>
   <activity>
   <intent-filter>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <other2>
      <some>
   </other2>
</other>
```