# Format apache2 virtual host conf using xmllint

Tags: linux, apache, command-line, xmllint

I would like to smart indent my apache2 virtual host conf files.
I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16090892) how to smart indent xml files. But virtual host conf files are not valid xml files.

For instance if I try using xmllint on the 000-default.conf which is given in the apache2 repository, I get an error :

```
$ cat 000-default.conf | xmllint --format -
-:1: parser error : error parsing attribute name
<VirtualHost *:80>
             ^
-:1: parser error : attributes construct error
<VirtualHost *:80>
             ^
-:1: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag VirtualHost line 1
<VirtualHost *:80>
             ^
-:1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<VirtualHost *:80>
             ^
```

Does any one have a clue on how to handle this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, apache2 config files are not XML files. `xmllint` is a program to (inter alia) reformat XML files. It will not work on apache2 config files. Therefore, do not use `xmllint` on apache2 config files, and you will avoid the errors you highlight above.

You would be better using an editor (see [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/apache-mode.el) for emacs apache2 mode), or a program written for reformatting apache2 config files.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I do not understand your sentence 'Therefore, do use xmllint on apache2 config files, and you will avoid the errors you highlight above.'

Comment: It was missing the vital word 'not' - now fixed.