# Is there any command to indent xml from the terminal?

Tags: xml, linux

> xmllint fileName - checks if the xml defined is right..

Is there any command to indent xml from terminal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090869/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-the-command-line

Comment: xmllint --format filename "prints" the indented output. Is there any command to indent an xmlfile ?In eclipse CTRL+I indents any given piece of code..Similarly is there any command available?

Answer (score 4):

xmllint does have a --format option:

```
--format
       Reformat and reindent the output. The XMLLINT_INDENT environment
       variable controls the indentation. The default value is two spaces
       " ").
```

Comment: I just found an answer in wiki of vim .Hope this may be useful. Open vimrc file -> au FileType xml exe ":silent %!xmllint --format --recover - 2>/dev/null"   ... ! Insert this in autocmd section.
Refer http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Format_your_xml_document_using_xmllint