# Compare-Object cmdlet wont work with "<!--" in a txt file

Tags: xml, powershell, select-string, compareobject

I am building another web server "web2", which must have the same configuration as web server "web1"

So after installing some software I need to edit the "web.config" on the "web2" server to match the one in the "web1" server

I am doing this from my laptop, so I copied both "web.config" files to my laptop running these commands:

```
    $w1="web1.server.local"
    $w2="web2.server.local"
    $myCred=(Get-Credential -credential "myAD\myUser")
    $file="C:\path\to\my\web.config"
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $w1 -Credential $myCred (Get-Content $args[0]) -ArgumentList $file | Set-content web1.txt
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $w2 -Credential $myCred (Get-Content $args[0]) -ArgumentList $file | Set-content web2.txt
```

Ok so now i have both "web.config" files from both servers named as: web1.txt and web2.txt

Here you can see a picture of the differences in the files (I got this using notepad++) as you can see there are only 4 differences.
please take in note I trim the files to only have 42 lines each

[image: all differences are in red boxes]

Then I tried to compare both files using the "Compare-Object" cmdlet but I am not getting an accurate info:

```
PS C:\> Compare-Object (Get-Content .\web1.txt) (Get-Content .\web2.txt)

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
            <=
            <=
```

The weird part is that if I just replace "< ! - - " with " < ! - - a" the output changes to:

```
PS C:\> Compare-Object (Get-Content .\web1.txt) (Get-Content .\web2.txt)

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
      <!--  =>
      <!--a <=
            <=
            <=
```

and then if I change the " - - >" to " - - >b" this is the output:

```
PS C:\> Compare-Object (Get-Content .\web1.txt) (Get-Content .\web2.txt)

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
      <!--  =>
      -->   =>
      <!--a <=
      -->b  <=
            <=
            <=
```

I try checking the encoding of the files, creating them in UTF-8, I also remove a lot of chunks of the xml file, remove a lot of brackets (on both files) but it never shows the difference.

Is there something I am missing?

Why Compare-Object cant tell if a plain file has an extra " - - > " or " < ! - - "

As you can see in the following image, I did a select-string  and in the web1.txt shown the line 11, but web2.txt didnot shown line 11, so those files are not the same.

[image: Compare-Object AND Select-String]

Thank you!!!

Comment: @mklement0 Looks like compare-object sorts the files before comparing.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like compare-object sorts the lines before it compares them.  It looks like you have two extra blank lines in the first file.  Otherwise, if the lines are sorted they are the same.  Minimal reproducible example:

file1.xml:

```
<top>

  <inner1>
  </inner1>

  <!--
  <inner2>
  </inner2>
  -->
</top>
```

file2.xml:

```
<top>
  <!--
  <inner1>
  </inner1>
  -->

  <inner2>
  </inner2>

</top>
```

```
compare-object (cat file1.xml) (cat file2.xml) 


InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
            <=
            <=
```

```
cat file1.xml | sort




  -->
  <!--
  </inner1>
  </inner2>
  <inner1>
  <inner2>
</top>
<top>


cat file2.xml | sort


  -->
  <!--
  </inner1>
  </inner2>
  <inner1>
  <inner2>
</top>
<top>
```

Syncwindow example:

file1

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

file2

```
line3
line4
```

Looks like it gives up looking for equal ones in that sync window:

```
compare-object (cat file1) (cat file2) -SyncWindow 1

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
line3       =>
line1       <=
line2       <=
line3       <=

compare-object (cat file1) (cat file2)

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
line1       <=
line2       <=
```

Here's an old blog post where the default syncwindow used to be 5:  http://fatbeards.blogspot.com/2009/01/compare-object-syncwindow-parameter.html

Comment: Nicely done. Yes, by default all objects - lines, in this case - are compared, irrespective of position; there's the `-SyncWindow` parameter to modify this behavior, but, frankly, I've never fully understood how it works.

Comment: @mklement0 I added an example.

Comment: Thanks, I've dug a little deeper and I think that `-SyncWindow N` roughly means: A sliding window of `N+1` elements from the start of the two collections is processed, with consumed elements (those whose equality status could conclusively be determined) potentially output and removed from the collections, with the reduced collections processed recursively.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it just add more confusion to me

Comment: when I do the -SyncWindow 1 I get almost ALL the lines, I dont understand

Comment: Don't worry about the syncwindow.  Basically the two files are almost identical if you sort the lines.