# XML log file printing to pretty

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml, pretty-print

I am trying to format output file using XML structure. Tried xml and lxml but no luck for now.
Currently output file look like:

```
<root><time>2021-07-28 10:27:49,869 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT</time><modification_request id="11d18Dqwerty" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0"><version>v_.0156</version><objectclass>objectID</objectclass><identifier qwerty>123321</identifier><modification operation="delete"><valueObject ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0:type="8"><objectA>123321</objectA></valueObject></modification></qw2:modifyRequest>
<time>2021-07-28 10:27:49,881 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT</time><modification_response id="11d18Dqwerty" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0"><version>v_.0156</version><objectclass>objectID</objectclass><identifier qwerty>123321</identifier><modification operation="delete"><valueObject ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0:type="8"><objectA>123321</objectA></valueObject></modification></qw2:modifyRequest>
<time>2021-07-28 10:27:51,834 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT</time><modification_request id="11d18Dqwerty" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0"><version>v_.0156</version><objectclass>objectID</objectclass><identifier qwerty>123321</identifier><modification operation="delete"><valueObject ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0:type="8"><objectA>123321</objectA></valueObject></modification></qw2:modifyRequest>
<time>2021-07-28 10:27:51,854 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT</time><modification_response id="11d18Dqwerty" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0"><version>v_.0156</version><objectclass>objectID</objectclass><identifier qwerty>123321</identifier><modification operation="delete"><valueObject ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0:type="8"><objectA>123321</objectA></valueObject></modification></qw2:modifyRequest>
<time>2021-07-28 10:27:52,182 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT</time><modification_request id="11d18Dqwerty" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0"><version>v_.0156</version><objectclass>objectID</objectclass><identifier qwerty>123321</identifier><modification operation="delete"><valueObject ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0:type="8"><objectA>123321</objectA></valueObject></modification></qw2:modifyRequest>
<time>2021-07-28 10:27:52,201 qwer123 instanceA 10.10.10.1 aaaaa/111 ABC DEFAULT</time><modification_response id="11d18Dqwerty" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0"><version>v_.0156</version><objectclass>objectID</objectclass><identifier qwerty>123321</identifier><modification operation="delete"><valueObject ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0" ytrew:qw2="url:qwertyu:qwerty:qwer:qw:qwer:0:0:type="8"><objectA>123321</objectA></valueObject></modification></qw2:modifyRequest></root>
```

Using this code right here:

```
import lxml.etree as etree
xml_input = etree.parse(r'output\output.txt')
print(etree.tostring(xml_input, pretty_print=True),file = open(r'output\output.txt','a'))
file.close()
```

How can I improve code for this kind of input? What is done wrong? Thanks everyone for any advice.

Comment: Hey, @mzjn, yes it does. I've checked now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not long ago have asked question and found the solution.

I have taken code from [How to pretty print XML from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090869/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-the-command-line?rq=1)

Where xml.dom.minidom is used.

```
import xml.dom.minidom
with open(r'output\output.txt', 'r+') as file:
   s = file.read()
   pretty = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(s).toprettyxml()
with open(r'output\output.txt', 'w') as writer:
   writer.write(pretty)
```

Now output looks like expected.