SQL Server's bcp queryout saves XML file in one line, any way to format this?
I created a SQL Server stored procedure that returns data in XML format. I use FOR XML PATH in it to get the target format.
Everything works fine, file is readable (multiple lines), but after using bcp queryout, everything is written in one line.
This is my xp_cmdshell command:
DECLARE @strbcpcmd NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @strbcpcmd = 'bcp "exec dbo.XMLGenerator @DateFrom = ''2024-10-01'', @DateTo = ''2024-10-01''" queryout "c:\Test\Test.xml" -S (local) -w -T -d ' + DB_NAME()

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @strbcpcmd

I would like the file to be user readable and display formatted data. Is there a way to do this or do I need to use an external tool outside of BCP?

That's purely a presentation thing. xml, in SQL Server, is also stored without linebreaks, just when you open the XML tools, such as XML, format it for human readability.

What CLI tool should I use to format that file? Already tried "tidy", but it shows many errors. Because of missing declaration, input encoding and not recognized tag names.

Tools are off-topic here, but google xml pretty cli or check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090869/how-to-pretty-print-xml-from-the-command-line

Can I use STUFF to add new line and \t chars?

No, this isn't a task for T-SQL.

You could use something like this Format-Xml PowerShell function. This would also "solve" the problem of using xp_cmdshell; you shouldn't be using SQL Server to invoke command prompt to run bcp to connect back to the SQL Server. Just launch Powershell and execute bcp from there.

Thanks, now I think users will use Notepad++ + XML Tools plugin + Pretty print option if they want to change something in a file.
